# SQL Update with multiple inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, inner-join

Using MSSQL

Looking for confirmation that my code is correct. Asking because I understand the possibility of messing up the SQL database if the statement is incorrect.

```
 query = ('UPDATE ProjectBridge.JobNumber, ProjectOffice.ProjectName,Client.ClientName'
         'SET ProjectBridge.JobNumber = '1205665', 
          ProjectOffice.ProjectName = 'The new name',
          Client.ClientName = 'New Client',
         'FROM ProjectBridge '
         'INNER JOIN ProjectOffice '
         'ON ProjectBridge.PJBId=ProjectOffice.PJBId '
         'INNER JOIN Client '
         'ON ProjectOffice.ClientId=Client.ClientId '
         'WHERE ProjectBridge.JobNumber LIKE '1205666%')
```

Also I have seen:

```
'UPDATE ProjectBridge.JobNumber as Val1'
'SET Val1 = 1205665'
```

Is this the correct use of the "as" statement?

Comment: Is this SQL Server? If so it has basic syntax errors. Why have you got every line in single quotes? The `SET` keyword should only be present once.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot update **multiple** table at once. Only one table should be updated per `UPDATE` command even though you are allowed to join tables. Second, you update statement has error on the syntax. There should always be single `SET` clause in an `update` statement. If you have multiple columns to update, separate it by a comma.

Comment: [I believe in MySQL you can update more than one table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Comment: @MartinSmith whoahh is this really working?  I assume the OP is using sqlserver because of the syntax used in the join.

Comment: Confirmed they are using SQL Server anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your update statement without actually changing anything, but see if it compiles and how many rows it would effect, try something like this:

```
query = ('UPDATE ProjectBridge.JobNumber, ProjectOffice.ProjectName,Client.ClientName'
         'SET ProjectBridge.JobNumber = ProjectBridge.JobNumber, 
         'SET ProjectOffice.ProjectName = ProjectOffice.ProjectName,
         'SET Client.ClientName = Client.ClientName,
```